# Is there a better way to achieve this kind of row-wise operation?

Tags: python, python-polars

In my polars dataframes, I want to add a column that will indicate with a boolean whether the rest of the columns in the dataframe contained any "null" values.

I tried various approaches that I found online or suggested by AI, most using `with_columns` and  `pl.all()` to operate on all the columns but each failed for different reasons. Too many to list here.

Can someone suggest a solution for this?

My work around is to transpose the current dataframe, then use `.select(pl.col("*").is_null().any())`, and then transpose again and join with the original dataframe. But that seems inefficient especially considering that the polars documentation mentions that transposing is an expensive operation.

Comment: Can you include an example input and expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `with_columns` will append the following columns

`pl.all().is_null().any().suffix("_has_nulls")` indicates per columns, if any row has a null value in that column. The `suffix` will append the columns rather than replacing the source column.

`pl.any_horizontal(pl.all().is_null())` indicates if any columns in the current row have a null value.

`pl.any_horizontal(pl.all().is_null().any()).alias("df_has_nulls")` will indicate if any value in the dataframe is null.

```py
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame({
    "a": [1,2,3,4],
    "b": ['1',"2","3","4"],
    "c": [1,2,None,4],
    "d": ['1',"2","3",None],
})

df = df.with_columns(
    pl.all().is_null().any().suffix("_has_nulls"),
    pl.any_horizontal(pl.all().is_null()).alias("row_has_nulls"),
    pl.any_horizontal(pl.all().is_null().any()).alias("df_has_nulls"),
)

print(df)
```

Result:

```
shape: (4, 10)
┌─────┬─────┬──────┬──────┬─────────────┬─────────────┬─────────────┬─────────────┬───────────────┬──────────────┐
│ a   ┆ b   ┆ c    ┆ d    ┆ a_has_nulls ┆ b_has_nulls ┆ c_has_nulls ┆ d_has_nulls ┆ row_has_nulls ┆ df_has_nulls │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---         ┆ ---         ┆ ---         ┆ ---         ┆ ---           ┆ ---          │
│ i64 ┆ str ┆ i64  ┆ str  ┆ bool        ┆ bool        ┆ bool        ┆ bool        ┆ bool          ┆ bool         │
╞═════╪═════╪══════╪══════╪═════════════╪═════════════╪═════════════╪═════════════╪═══════════════╪══════════════╡
│ 1   ┆ 1   ┆ 1    ┆ 1    ┆ false       ┆ false       ┆ true        ┆ true        ┆ false         ┆ true         │
│ 2   ┆ 2   ┆ 2    ┆ 2    ┆ false       ┆ false       ┆ true        ┆ true        ┆ false         ┆ true         │
│ 3   ┆ 3   ┆ null ┆ 3    ┆ false       ┆ false       ┆ true        ┆ true        ┆ true          ┆ true         │
│ 4   ┆ 4   ┆ 4    ┆ null ┆ false       ┆ false       ┆ true        ┆ true        ┆ true          ┆ true         │
└─────┴─────┴──────┴──────┴─────────────┴─────────────┴─────────────┴─────────────┴───────────────┴──────────────┘
```

Answer (score 3):

If i understand you correctly you want to check if the horizontal sum of Null values is greater than 0. You can count the number null-values by combining `pl.sum_horizontal` and `pl.all().isnull()`.

```
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame({
    "col1": [1, 2, None, None],
    "col2": [1, 2, 3, None]
})

df.with_columns(row_with_none = pl.sum_horizontal(pl.all().is_null()) > 1)

shape: (4, 3)
┌──────┬──────┬───────────────┐
│ col1 ┆ col2 ┆ row_with_none │
│ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---           │
│ i64  ┆ i64  ┆ bool          │
╞══════╪══════╪═══════════════╡
│ 1    ┆ 1    ┆ false         │
│ 2    ┆ 2    ┆ false         │
│ null ┆ 3    ┆ false         │
│ null ┆ null ┆ true          │
└──────┴──────┴───────────────┘
```

Answer (score 1):

There is also the [List API](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/list.html):

```py
df.with_columns(
   row = pl.concat_list(pl.all().is_null())
).with_columns(
   any = pl.col("row").list.any(),
   all = pl.col("row").list.all()
)
```

```py
shape: (4, 5)
┌──────┬──────┬────────────────┬───────┬───────┐
│ col1 ┆ col2 ┆ row            ┆ any   ┆ all   │
│ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---            ┆ ---   ┆ ---   │
│ i64  ┆ i64  ┆ list[bool]     ┆ bool  ┆ bool  │
╞══════╪══════╪════════════════╪═══════╪═══════╡
│ 1    ┆ 1    ┆ [false, false] ┆ false ┆ false │
│ 2    ┆ 2    ┆ [false, false] ┆ false ┆ false │
│ null ┆ 3    ┆ [true, false]  ┆ true  ┆ false │
│ null ┆ null ┆ [true, true]   ┆ true  ┆ true  │
└──────┴──────┴────────────────┴───────┴───────┘
```